# Tilemap is shaking on camera move in Phaser

Tags: phaser, typescript

I am creating simple 100x100 tilemap using `Tiled` and `Phaser`, nothing more, but when I move the camero around, the "map scrolling animation" is not smooth, and there are noise/breaks/shakes of the map. I have no idea what is going on, specially this is only game showing the map. I found somewhere that it can be Chrome issue bug regarding animation frame, but it is the same on Firefox.

Can you advise?

https://youtu.be/AOGimEWpdjo

Code example: https://github.com/Lazarencjusz/phaser-tilemap-shakes

I am using `Tiled` to create `json` of the map, then loading it into my app.

Key code is:

Camera creation:

```
  const cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    const controlConfig = {
      camera: this.cameras.main,
      left: cursors.left,
      right: cursors.right,
      up: cursors.up,
      down: cursors.down,
      acceleration: 0.3,
      drag: 0.0017,
      maxSpeed: 0.75,
    };

    this.#cameraControls = new Phaser.Cameras.Controls.SmoothedKeyControl(
      controlConfig,
    );
```

Map is created like:

```
this.#map = this.scene.make.tilemap({ key: AssetTilemapKey.testMap1 })
this.#tileset1 = this.#map.addTilesetImage(
      TiledTileset.grassRoad,
      AsseTilesetImageKey.grassRoad,
    );
this.#map.createLayer(
        TiledLayers.ground,
        this.#tileset1,
      )
```

Comment: Stepping frame by frame through your video, it looks like about one frame in four there's a larger lurch in motion than the previous three, giving that juddering shaky appearance. A couple possibilities I can think of are missing/incorrect delta time correction in the movement, a "beat frequency" misalignment between your logical update step and the rendering framerate, or an error in some code that's trying to adjust the map by full-tile increments.

Comment: Just want to link this question, with your [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76885187/tilemap-is-shaking-on-camera-move-in-phaser). If you do find a soultion, would be great if you could share. Thanks in advance

Comment: I found this one: https://www.dynetisgames.com/2018/02/24/manage-big-maps-phaser-3/ but didn't have any time to test it yet